# How to convert as.character("%d-%m-%Y hh:mm") to "%d-%m-%y"

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dplyr, lubridate

I have these times `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`

```
               date
1  14-02-2020 21:02
2  30-04-2019 10:46
3  26-01-2019 10:10
4  26-04-2018 13:38
5  13-07-2017 10:24
6  03-02-2020 13:38
7  16-09-2020 19:35
8  10-02-2020 04:46
9  08-09-2017 13:34
10 08-09-2017 13:34
```

I want to format to `dd-mm-yyyy`. I tried

`p %>% mutate(new = format(as.Date(times, "%d-%m-%Y hh:mm"), "%d%m%y"))`

But that did not work

```
p <- structure(list(times = c("14-02-2020 21:02", "30-04-2019 10:46", 
"26-01-2019 10:10", "26-04-2018 13:38", "13-07-2017 10:24", "03-02-2020 13:38", 
"16-09-2020 19:35", "10-02-2020 04:46", "08-09-2017 13:34", "08-09-2017 13:34"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your dput, the p$dates variable is in date and time format. When you parse it with `as.Date()`, exclude the hour/minute/second signals.

```
p %>% mutate(dmy_date = as.Date(times,  format = "%d-%m-%Y"))

              times   dmy_date
1  14-02-2020 21:02 2020-02-14
2  30-04-2019 10:46 2019-04-30
3  26-01-2019 10:10 2019-01-26
4  26-04-2018 13:38 2018-04-26
5  13-07-2017 10:24 2017-07-13
6  03-02-2020 13:38 2020-02-03
7  16-09-2020 19:35 2020-09-16
8  10-02-2020 04:46 2020-02-10
9  08-09-2017 13:34 2017-09-08
10 08-09-2017 13:34 2017-09-08
```

Answer (score 1):

Tons of ways to do it. I like the date one. But if you just want to strip things off a character vector you can do

```
p$times <- substr(p$times,1,10)

> p
        times
1  14-02-2020
2  30-04-2019
3  26-01-2019
4  26-04-2018
5  13-07-2017
6  03-02-2020
7  16-09-2020
8  10-02-2020
9  08-09-2017
10 08-09-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `sub`

```
sub("\\s+.*", "", p$times)
```